# web design is not fit on mobile device

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am making a web site for desktop and mobile screen. There is no mistake on desktop screens. But When I showing on the mobile phone screen. My design is shrinking. And İt is not fit on mobile screen. I am using Boostrap version number is 5. But I tried to use width: 100%; but ıt is not working. Also, I am making on .net web application. How can I fix it?

You can check it:

[image]

What İ expected: ( iPad version )

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

  </head>



    <header class="head navigation fixed-top ">
        <img />
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a href="Index">Main Page</a>

            <a href="blog">Blog</a>
            <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=905304500247&amp;text=&amp;source=&amp;data=">Contact</a>

        </nav>

    </header>
    <br />


    <div style="width: 100%; height: 750px; background-color: yellow;  ">

     



        <div class="example">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 750px;" class="background-image" src="~/Img/web_site.png">
            <div class="overlay-text">
                <h1>Welcome to our Web Page</h1>
                <p> </p>
            </div>




        </div>


    </div>


    <div style="width: 100%; height: 450px; background-color: black; padding-left: 20px; text-align: center; ">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <h2 style="color: white; top: 50%; right: 50%; ">We're happy to be a leading software</h2>
        <h2 style="color: white; top: 50%; right: 50%;">company in İstanbul</h2>
        <h2 style="color: white; top: 50%; right: 50%;">solutions for today's enterprise companies.</h2>

        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=905304500247&amp;text=&amp;source=&amp;data="><button onclick="window.location.href='/Home/login_page'" class="btncomminicate">Contact Us</button></a>

    </div>
```

Css code:

```
   @@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        }

    }

    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .example {
        position: relative;
    }

    .overlay-text {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    }


    .head {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: #000000;
        display: flex;
        /*  justify-content: center; */
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .navigation a {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

        .navigation a::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: -6px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 3px;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transform-origin: right;
            transform: scaleX(0);
            transition: transform .5s;
        }

        .navigation a:hover::after {
            transform-origin: left;
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }

    .btncomminicate {
        width: 500px;
        height: 50px;
        background: transparent;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 6px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        color: yellow;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

        .btncomminicate:hover {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            background: yellow;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 6px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            color: black;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }
```

Comment: After your issue has been fixed, you should consult a web designer with `responsive web design` experience and/or bring your code to Code Review for review and/or read into responsive web design yourself.  You are overusing `<br>` out of its scope (linebreak)  which is not creating a spacings between elements.

Comment: I will do that. You can believe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because once you're smaller than 500px wide, the "Contact Us" button which is set to 500px width is wider than 100% width and creates the dead space on the right.

Specifically these lines:

```css
.btncomminicate {
  width: 500px;
}

.btncomminicate:hover {
      width: 500px;
}
```

You can adjust this to be either a percent width (`width: 75%`) or by letting the width calculate automatically (remove the 2 lines above).

Personally the way I usually handle buttons is to add padding instead of setting the width & height (your `height: 50px` can be removed if you use this approach):

```css
/* Something like this - adjust units to your tastes */
.btncomminicate {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer is fully working.